# How do I get a row of the same type from one table or another table along with the information about from which table it was

Tags: mysql, sql, go, mariadb

Let's say I have tables:

```
create table people ( 
    human_id bigint auto_increment primary key, 
    birthday datetime );

create table students ( 
    id bigint auto_increment primary key, 
    human_id bigint unique key not null, 
    group_id bigint not null );

create table teachers ( 
    id bigint auto_increment primary key, 
    human_id bigint unique key not null, 
    academic_degree varchar(20) );

create table library_access ( 
    access_id bigint auto_increment primary key, 
    human_id bigint not null, 
    accessed_on datetime );
```

Now I want to display information about a library access, along with the information whether it was a student or a teacher (and then the id corresponding to the table) (let's say I want something like `SELECT access_id,id,true_if_student_false_if_teacher FROM library_access`), in an idiomatic way.

How do I form the query (in case such database was already deployed) and what are better and more idiomatic ways to solve that problem (in case it wasn't deployed so far).

MariaDB 5.5, database accessed by Go and nothing else.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you need to know which table the data comes from.  You can use `union all` for this:

```
select la.access_id, s.id, 'Students' as source_table
from library_access la 
    join students s on la.human_id = s.human_id
union all
select la.access_id, t.id, 'Teachers' as source_table
from library_access la 
    join teachers t on la.human_id = t.human_id
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems so simple now. Just one question to make sure I understand: the ALL keyword is needed only when I have a person which is both a student and a teacher?

Comment: @ArchieT -- you're welcome. To answer your question, no, `union all` is used to combine results from multiple queries -- each `sql` statement must have the same number of columns.  Plus `union all` is faster than `union`  by itself since `union` removes duplicates.  In your scenario, that should never occur.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your tables or any idea as to what you want returned in the select statement:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    people a,
        students b,
        teachers c,
        library_access d
WHERE   a.human_id = b.human_id
    AND a.human_id = c.human_id
    AND a.human_id = d.human_id
```